# Get post ID outside of the loop

Tags: posts

I am trying to accomplish something somewhat simple I think. I have a menu item at the top of my page that I want to link to the latest post in a certain category. I just need to get the post ID of the latest post in the category so I can pass it to the menu. I want to do this outside of the loop and create a function in functions.php that will return the post ID. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here is a function that does just that:

```
function get_lastest_post_of_category($cat){
    $args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 1, 'order'=> 'DESC', 'orderby' => 'date', 'category__in' => (array)$cat);
    $post_is = get_posts( $args );
    return $post_is[0]->ID;
}
```

Usage: say my category id is 22 then:

```
$last_post_ID = get_lastest_post_of_category(22);
```

you can also pass an array of categories to this function.

Comment: `$post_is[0]->ID` You can't do this, unless you are running master branch of PHP I believe, just thought I would mention it if anyone was copy / pasting you example. If you wanted to do it in one line, you would have to do `reset( $post_is )->ID`

Comment: Also, if you pass an array to this function, it will result in a double array, instead you probably want to array cast the `$cat` variable: `'category__in' => (array) $cat`

Comment: Awesome, did exactly what I was looking for, thanks!