# Exclude newest post from category X but show rest

Tags: posts, query-posts

I would like to show all posts but only exclude the NEWEST post from the 'Featured' category, other posts from this cat should display. Any idea what I should add to the loop to achieve this? I want all other posts from other cats to be displayed aswell!

Answer (score 1):

Since by default the loop will retrieve the posts in descending order by date, you can do something like the following:

Outside the loop:

```
$featured_flag = false;
```

Inside the loop:

```
if(in_category('Featured')) {
    if($featured_flag) {
        the_content();
    }
    else {
        $featured_flag = true;
    }
}
else {
    the_content();
}
```

The first time a post from the Featured category is encountered (i.e. the most recent) it will be ignored and the `$featured_flag` will be set to `true`. Subsequent times through the loop `the_content()` will be displayed.

**Edit**: To account for pagination you could change `$featured_flag` to a `$_SESSION` variable. That way the true/false value will persist across multiple pages, and once it's been set to `true` posts will continue to display properly. Thanks for pointing out the error of my ways Bainternet :)

Comment: that's nice, and would work unless you have pagination, which will get messed up.

Comment: Edited to account for pagination (theoretically). Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: That will make sure the post is only seen once, and if you simply reload you won't see that post again untill  a new session is started,  and it will still mess up the pagination, think about it, you have a posts_per_page which will get a number of posts as defined and the loop will show one less.

Comment: Ya, you're right. I didn't really think it through fully. It's late and I need to sleep :)

Answer (score 1):

A while back i posted a simple function that [gets latest post in a certain category](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/12575/get-post-id-outside-of-the-loop/12581#12581):

```
function get_lastest_post_of_category($cat){
    $args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 1, 'order'=> 'DESC', 'orderby' => 'date', 'category__in' => (array)$cat);
    $post_is = get_posts( $args );
    return $post_is[0]->ID;
}
```

So once you have that function you can use use WP_Query or query_posts and using the `post__not_in` parameter you can exclude that post, so something like:

```
query_posts(array(`post__not_in` => array(get_lastest_post_of_category($CAT_ID))));
```

just change $CAT_ID to the actual category id